# icosphere passes through all planes even with collision on in physics tab

Tags: physics

See animation below:

Red ball passes through everything.

Blue ball passes through both stairs and green plane but finally collides with blue plane.

I have been trying to fix this problem for 4 hours now.

Blender file: [image]

Animation: [image: Planes physics]

Physics:

- Blue plane, green plane and stairs all have the same physics with just the collision on (no settings changed): [image: Planes physics]
- Blue ball and red ball have the same physics, collision and soft body turned on:[image: Balls physics]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to simplify the physics models.  Here is what I have for the blue ball and then the stairs:

[image]

[image]

I didn't change any of the soft body parameters, using the defaults instead. I did set the stairs to Passive and made sure the blue ball was active.

Since I didn't tune the rigid body parameters, the balls tend to pass part way through the stairs, but they do bounce and roll down the stairs.